# Do GCC and Clang optimize field-by-field struct copy?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, clang

E.g. given

```
typedef struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} A;

typedef struct B {
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
} B;

void f(B& b1, A& a2) {
    b1.d = a2.a;
    b1.e = a2.b;
    b1.f = a2.c;
}
```

`f` could be replaced by a `memcpy` (especially if the structs had more fields).

1. Will both versions produce equivalent code?
2. What if the structure we copy to has fewer fields than `A`? I.e.

   ```
   typedef struct C {
       int g;
       int h;
   } C;

   void h(C& c1, A& a2) {
       c1.g = a2.a;
       c1.h = a2.b;
   }
   ```

I am interested because I am generating code which includes struct copies like this, normally changing the order of fields, and I want to know if these cases should be treated specially.

C tag included because I expect behavior in C is the same (modulo pointers instead of references).

Comment: Is actually compiling and checking the generated code not an option? if not, why?

Comment: Have you checked the generated assembly (with optimizations enabled of course)?

Comment: This can only tell if it works for a specific compiler version, architecture, etc. but I was looking for a more general answer. However, it turns out to fail in the simple case already.

Comment: My recommendation is not to rely on behaviour of a specific compiler. Different compilers and later versions of the same compiler may optimise better than the current used one, so you might make the code less readable for no reason (since the compiler will eventually optimise it as well as possible).

Comment: As the question mentions, this is generated code, so I am somewhat less concerned about readability (of course, it's a bonus all other things being equal). And for that matter, whether a single `memcpy` line is less readable than _N_ field assignment lines, where you need to check all fields are assigned to corresponding fields, is quite arguable.

Comment: Still, how do you know that some other compiler (or a later version of the same compiler) will not favour instead the way you are going to reject now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testcase does not load and store enough memory for a conversion to memcpy to be worthwhile. Using twice as many members:

```
typedef struct A { int a, b, c, p, q, r; } A;
typedef struct B { int d, e, f, s, t, u; } B;
void f(B& b1, A& a2) {
  b1.d = a2.a;
  b1.e = a2.b;
  b1.f = a2.c;
  b1.s = a2.p;
  b1.t = a2.q;
  b1.u = a2.r;
}
```

... [LLVM optimizes the code](https://godbolt.org/g/9N4xt8) to:

```
f(B&, A&):                             # @f(B&, A&)
        movups  (%rsi), %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
        movl    16(%rsi), %eax
        movl    %eax, 16(%rdi)
        movl    20(%rsi), %eax
        movl    %eax, 20(%rdi)
        retq
```

... with an unaligned 16-byte load/store copying the first four members.

Comment: Thanks. I did try larger examples, but unfortunately only with GCC.

Comment: gcc-7 -O3 generates essentially the same code as shown here (movdqu instead of the first movups).

Answer (score 4):

According to godbolt.org, x86-64 gcc 6.2 with -O2 produces

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
mov DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi+4]
mov DWORD PTR [rdi+4], eax
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi+8]
mov DWORD PTR [rdi+8], eax
```

for field-by-field copy,

```
mov rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
mov QWORD PTR [rdi], rax
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi+8]
mov DWORD PTR [rdi+8], eax
```

for `memcpy`. Both clang and icc have similar differences. A bit disappointing.

Comment: I wonder why this is. If the second bit of assembly is indeed faster than the first, one would think the optimizer would identify this opportunity. I can't see a reason why the optimization would be unsound. Maybe it's not actually faster on an x86 chip?

Comment: @ChrisBeck Maybe. But if they are equally fast, the second should be better for the instruction cache, and if the first is faster, it should be generated for `memcpy` as well. Maybe the optimizer only tries to reduce code size starting from some threshold?

Answer (score 2):

The general answer: depends on. As a free function generally it will generate a code pretty similar to `std::memmove` (using temporary variables to avoid possible overlaps, see [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove)), but after inlining it can be folded as `std::memcpy` with possible optimizations (by SSE for example).

EDIT:

You can see fully optimized output and try to experiment with gcc.godbolt by using `volatile` variables: such a trick allows to see optimizations but forbid the compiler to omit results inside "battle" code. Take [this](https://godbolt.org/g/kOZMhq).

Comment: That's possible if and only if the fields are POD types without overloaded assignment operators

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername yes, but not exactly. Firstly, the code was about `int` fields, and secondly, today compilers are extremely smart and can analyze even user defined operators to simplify such assignments and inline them. But all of these kinds of optimizations are implementation defined and should be analyzed closely for every compiler and `O` level.

Comment: Well, the whole point of overloading an assignment operator would be to provide a behavior different from the default one. So it's quite unlikely that such an operator would yield a result similar to memcpy.